# Unable to parse XML data into Java object using XPath

Tags: xml, rest, xpath, java-8, odata

I'm making a call to OData service (similar to REST API call) using my Java program and I'm getting response as well in the XML format. In response, I get an XML where I need to read specific XML properties/attributes only hence I'm using XPath to do so. However, the problem is I'm able to read only 1 set (or the 1st set) of XML attributes but not others. What I understand with XPath is that I need to give a parent attribute name so that parsing will start from that level to child attributes but some how it is not working as required.

Following is the XML response and here there is each `<entry>` tag and within each `<entry>` tag, I want to read only the child attributes/nodes which comes under `<m:properties>`, for instance:

```
<m:properties>
<d:Role_MappingId>3503</d:Role_MappingId>
<d:Org_RelationshipId>1</d:Org_RelationshipId>
<d:Role_Id>1</d:Role_Id>
<d:Role_Mapping_Active>true</d:Role_Mapping_Active>
<d:RoleName>test</d:RoleName>
<d:Role_Description>
dummy description,
</d:Role_Description>
<d:RoleGroup>dummy group</d:RoleGroup>
</m:properties>
```

Whole XML response for your reference:

```
<link href="Relationships(1)/RoleToRelationshipMappings" rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/RoleToRelationshipMappings" title="RoleToRelationshipMappings" type="application/atom+xml;type=feed">
    <m:inline>
        <feed xml:base="http://localhost:8080/com.test/PortalOData.svc/">
            <id>...</id>
            <title type="text">RoleToRelationshipMappings</title>
            <updated>2019-04-03T15:24:15.429+05:30</updated>
            <author>...</author>
            <link href="Relationships(1)/RoleToRelationshipMappings" rel="self" title="RoleToRelationshipMappings"/>
            <entry>
                <id>
http://localhost:8080/com.test/PortalOData.svc/RoleToRelationshipMappings(3503)
</id>
                <title type="text">RoleToRelationshipMappings</title>
                <updated>2019-04-03T15:24:15.429+05:30</updated>
                <category term="cmo.test.portal.servicelayer.odataentities.RoleToRelationshipMapping" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"/>
                <link href="RoleToRelationshipMappings(3503)" rel="edit" title="RoleToRelationshipMapping"/>
                <content type="application/xml">
                    <m:properties>
                        <d:Role_MappingId>3503</d:Role_MappingId>
                        <d:Org_RelationshipId>1</d:Org_RelationshipId>
                        <d:Role_Id>1</d:Role_Id>
                        <d:Role_Mapping_Active>true</d:Role_Mapping_Active>
                        <d:RoleName>SNR</d:RoleName>
                        <d:Role_Description>
This entity can make a serial number request from a MAH,
</d:Role_Description>
                        <d:RoleGroup>SNR_REQUEST_TYPE</d:RoleGroup>
                    </m:properties>
                </content>
            </entry>
            <entry>...</entry>
            <entry>...</entry>
            <entry>...</entry>
            <entry>...</entry>
            <entry>...</entry>
            <entry>...</entry>
            <entry>...</entry>
            <entry>...</entry>
        </feed>
    </m:inline>
</link>
```

If you notice in above XML, parent node is **`<feed>`** and inside that there is **repeated `<entry>` nodes** and **for each `<entry>` node**, there are some child attributes but **I want to read only those attributes which falls under `<m:properties>` like `<d:Role_MappingId>` or `<d:Org_RelationshipId>`** and **for each `<entry>`**.

Problem is I'm able to read but for 1 `<entry>` only but not for other `<entry>`.
Please assist to fix or advise the root cause of it.

This is my Java program:

```
public Map<String, MetricModel> readResponse(BufferedReader bufferedReader) throws Exception {
    Map<String, MetricModel> map = null;
    List <String> roles = null;
    String line = "";
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
      response.append(line);
    }
    String xml = response.toString();
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = documentBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
    XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();

    try {
      if (xml.contains("entry") == false) {
        throw new Exception();
      } else {
        roles = new ArrayList<>();
        String expression = "/entry";
        NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
          Node nNode = nodeList.item(i);
          logger.info("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
          if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
            logger.info(
                "Role_Mapping_Id : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("d:Role_MappingId").item(0).getTextContent());
            logger.info("Org_Relationship_Id : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("d:Org_RelationshipId")
                .item(0)
                .getTextContent());
            logger.info("Role_Id : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("d:Role_Id").item(0).getTextContent());
            roles.add(eElement.getElementsByTagName("d:Role_Id").item(0).getTextContent()); //Adding roles to list

            logger.info("Role_Mapping_Active : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("d:Role_Mapping_Active")
                .item(0)
                .getTextContent());
            logger.info("RoleName : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("d:RoleName").item(0).getTextContent());
            logger.info(
                "Role_Description : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("d:Role_Description").item(0).getTextContent());
            logger.info("RoleGroup : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("d:RoleGroup").item(0).getTextContent());
          }
        }
      }
      map = prepareDataForMetricModel(roles);
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
      logger.info("finally block");
      return  map;
    }
```

Here in program, I currently used expression like

```
String expression = "/entry";
```

I changed this to following but still not able to read for all entries.

```
String expression = "/feed/entry";
```

Comment: Try learning the basics about xpath, a single slash is an absolute path, with double `//entry` is a relative path, probably what you want.

Comment: Is that really the complete XML? Are there no namespace declarations for the used prefixes like `m` or `d` (e.g. in the form `xmlns:m="http://example.com" xmlns:d="http://example.org"`)?